# Read error log for a certain day

Tags: php, command-line, grep, command

I have a large 1GB error log called "error_log" and I need to read the errors from a certain day only. I have this simple PHP code to achieve that:

```
<?php

$lines = `cat error_log | grep '[27-Aug'`;
echo $lines;

?>
```

For some reason this code outputs nothing when I tried it. I want to read errors that were logged on day 27 August so I use `[27-Aug'` as it's the prefix for each entry.

Is there something wrong in the above code? I'm sure of the file path as I tried the `head` command and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
grep '[27-Aug'
```

try

```
grep '\[27-Aug'
```

`[` is a special character and needs to be escaped

But change line to:

```
lines=$(grep '\[27-Aug' error_log)
```

Do not  `cat` to file to program that can read it itself.
Avoid using old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses like this `var=$(code)`

Comment: is there a missing `$` before lines variable?

Comment: now getting this error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in

Comment: @MichaelSamuel php is not my strength.  Try adding `$`

Comment: ok...just found `shell_exec` command is how this command should be run...thanks :)